# XML::Twig Parse Hash to twig handler sub

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

Hi,

I have the following XML::Twig code to print out some tag information. However instead of parsing an array to the twig handler sub I need to parse a hash instead.

```
my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    pretty_print => 'indented',
    twig_handlers =>{'tag1'=>sub{Modify_tag1_data(@_,\@Array_Vals,\@Array_Types)}}); 


sub Modify_tag1_data{
    my ( $twig, $tag1,$Array_Vals,$Array_Types) = @_;
    #
    $tag1 = $_->att('f');
    if($Array_Vals[$tag1] eq 'f' && $Array_Types[$tag1] eq 'test'){
        print $tag1 . "\n";
    }
}
```

However the code below, now containing the hashes instead of the arrays, gives an error saying symbo %Hash_Vals requires explicit package name and the same error for the variable %Hash_Types.

```
my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    pretty_print => 'indented',
    twig_handlers =>{'tag1'=>sub{Modify_tag1_data(@_,\%Hash_Vals,\%Hash_Types)}}); 


sub Modify_tag1_data{
    my ( $twig, $tag1,$Hash_Vals,$Hash_Types) = @_;
    #
    $tag1 = $_->att('f');
    if($Hash_Vals{$tag1} eq 'f' && $Hash_Types{$tag1} eq 'test'){
        print $tag1 . "\n";
    }
}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: "%Hash_Vals requires explicit package name" means you haven't declared `%Hash_Vals` correctly. But we can't see where you declare it, because you've only posted a snippet. Also in your sub - `$Hash_Vals` is not related to `$Hash_Vals{$tag1}`.

Comment: I would also suggest - don't use `twig_handlers` unless you really need to. If you're passing an anon sub with parameters, you're _probably_ better off just parsing the whole thing, and then modifying it afterwards.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use an older version of perl that crashes if I try and load all of the twig structure at once when the xml files become large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question seems a bit misleading. If you are getting: "%Hash_Vals requires explicit package name and the same error for the variable %Hash_Types."

... that means you haven't declared these variables. It's not a lot to do with `XML::Twig` or `XML` parsing at all.

In your sub, you're doing something strange too - I suspect you're not doing what you want with:

```
sub Modify_tag1_data{
    my ( $twig, $tag1,$Hash_Vals,$Hash_Types) = @_;
    #
    $tag1 = $_->att('f');
    if($Hash_Vals{$tag1} eq 'f' && $Hash_Types{$tag1} eq 'test'){
        print $tag1 . "\n";
    }
}
```

Because `$Hash_Vals` in your parameters has *no* connection with `$Hash_Vals{$tag1}` aside from looking similar. You *probably* want `$Hash_Vals -> {$tag1}` but it's hard to tell without knowing what `%Hash_Vals` actually contains.

Comment: Many thanks Sobrique. The problem was simply, as you have said, to use $Hash_Vals -> {$tag1}